# move python virtual env, permission problems

Tags: python, ubuntu, file-permissions, python-venv

I recently move my python virtual environments to a different location. I first encountered the problem of certain packages being unavailable when I activated the venv. Now I get "Permission denied" on everything.

I changed every occurence of the previous path, in every file in the venv directory, to the new one so the sha-bangs would no longer be a problem. They don't seem to be anymore.

Previous questions related to this topic have mentioned the ownership of the directory as the potential problem. I am using an ubuntu machine and I am not very knowledgeable about Linux but when I **ll** these directories I can see that I own them. (the result of **whoami** anyway).

Problems only arose once I moved the venv directory. So I don't think it is related to the *installing with sudo* stuff that I also read about.

Any ideas? your help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a linux file permissions issue, as you mention yourself

You can view the permissions on your files using `ls -l`

This will list the files in your current directory in "long" format.

eg:

```
ls -l

drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root    68 Jun 13 20:25 tuned
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4017 Feb 24  2022 vimrc
```

To make sure you have the correct permissions you need to follow two steps:

- step 1: Change ownership of the files
- step 2: Change the permissions of the files

Note that we are going to do this for the main directory of your project.

**Step 1: Change ownership**

you can change ownership of everything using this command:

`sudo chown -R user directory`

Replace `user` with your username (as returned by `whoami`)

Replace directory with your project directory`

`-R` means this is recursive and will affect all the subfiles and subdirectories.

**Step 2: Change permissions of the file**

you can change the access permissions using this command:

`sudo chmod -R 755 directory`

Replace `directory` with your project directory

`-R` means this is recursive and will affect all the subfiles and subdirectories.

755 is a permissions code. It stands for

- owning user can read, write, execute
- owning group can read and execute
- everyone else can read and execute

Once you've done this, you can check permissions again using `ls -l`.
This will have changed permissions on all your subdirectories, including the files in your virtual environment.

Comment: I did not change the owner since, as I mentioned, that was not necessary. But I did follow the second step as you suggested (without sudo though) and it  worked. Thank you for this clear, well detailed response.

Comment: Actually before you leave...
What is the "sudo" supposed to do in the chmod command? I am currently getting "bad interpreter: permission denied" when I try to use pip. (a different venv from the one I told worked fine).